# Is there a size limit to a blob for Utilities.unzip(blob) in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, zip, blob, filesize

I have a google script which accesses a website, finds a .zip file, unzips it, and extracts the relevant data from the relevant files.

I want to do the same thing, but for a different, larger .zip file on the same site.

I've accessed the .zip (using almost identical code), but it throws an error: "Could not unzip."

My code:

```
  var dir = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var b = dir.getBlob();
  var files = Utilities.unzip(b);
```

The only difference between the two files are these:

- File A ends with "Update%201.8.5.zip" and contains 9 files (5.46MB, 5.15MB zipped)
- File B ends with "260_185.zip" and contains 407 files (384MB, 280MB zipped)

This makes me think that there is a limit (size or number of files) to the Utilities.unzip() method. Can anyone confirm this, or is there something with the format of the filenames that is messing things up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) include the restriction

> URL Fetch data received:  100MB / day

so it seems your URL request could not actually produce a valid zip file.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the URL Fetch limits, Utilities.unzip(blob) has its own undisclosed limits.

I just tried to unzip a >200MB file that I get by using DriveApp.getFileById(id) and it returned

> El archivo contratacionesabiertas_bulk.csv.zip supera el tamaño de archivo máximo permitido.

(Translation by Google Translate)

> The contratacionesabiertas_bulk.csv.zip file exceeds the maximum file size allowed.