# Google Script - How to use unzip

Tags: google-apps-script, unzip

I am downloading a .zip from a website.  It contains one .txt file.  I would like to access the data in the txt and write it to a spreadsheet.  I'm open to either accessing it directly and not extracting the zip OR extracting the zip, saving the txt to a Google Drive Folder, and accessing it once it is saved.

When I use `Utilities.unzip()`, I can never get it to unzip the file and usually end up with an "Invalid argument" error.  In the code below, the last section before `else` contains the unzip command.  It successfully saves the file to the correct Google Folder but then I can't extract it.

```js
function myFunction() {
  // define where to gather data from
  var url = '<insert url here>';
  var filename = "ReportUploadTesting05.zip";
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    // muteHttpExceptions: true,
    // validateHttpsCertificates: false,
    followRedirects: true  // Default is true anyway.
  });

  // get spreadsheet for follow up info
  var Sp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
    // get folder details of spreadsheet for saving future files
    var folderURL = getParentFolder(Sp);
    var folderID = getIdFromUrl(folderURL);
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    
    // save zip file
    var blob = response.getBlob();
    var file = folder.createFile(blob);
    file.setName(filename);
    file.setDescription("Downloaded from " + url);
    var fileID = file.getId();
    Logger.log(fileID);
    Logger.log(blob)
    
    // extract zip (not working)
    file.setContent('application/zip')
    var fileUnzippedBlob = Utilities.unzip(file);  // invalid argument error occurs here
    var filename = 'unzipped file'
    var fileUnzipped = folder.createFile(fileUnzippedBlob)
    fileUnzipped.setName(filename)
  }
  else {
    Logger.log(response.getResponseCode());
  }
}
```

I've followed the instructions on the [Utilities page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzip(BlobSource)).  I can get their exact example to work.  I've tried creating a .zip on my computer, uploading it to Google Drive and attempted to open it unsuccessfully.  Obviously there are some subtleties of using the unzip that I'm missing.

Could you help me understand this?

Comment: `unzip` expects Blob type, so you can try do `Utilities.unzip(blob)`

Comment: @Kos, thanks, yes I had tried that and just did so again to double check.  I grabbed the `blob` variable which I had already created and placed it into the `Utilities.unzip`.  It results in the same error message at the same line.

Just to say something specifically to that point, I read that files are blobs and calling `getBlob()` on it is redundant.

Comment: With my limited testing it seems like if you skip this code `file.setContent('application/zip')` and don't setContent at all, the code works just fine for me. Note: I uploaded a zipped file to google drive and tested it!

Comment: @JackBrown, thanks, I had tried that and just tried again at your suggestion but still end up with the same error at the same line.  This function seems so straight forward!?

Comment: I see you are storing the zip via createFile, are you able to manually extract that zip outside of apps script? Maybe the problem is in the save step. By the way, I would call getBlob() on the file, even if it is redundant (and I'm not sure it is) it's a good idea for clarity.

Comment: @CameronRoberts, thanks for chiming in!  I am able to download the zip file to computer and unzip it.  When I do so, the size is 540 KB.  When I try to unzip it using "Zip Extractor" (Google Drive App), it is taking forever for the extractor tab to go past 'loading' and when it finally loads, it says the file is 4 GB!  I also tried skipping the `createFile` and just putting the blob directly into the `unzip` but that was unsuccessful.

Comment: These conversations got me looking more closely at the content type and I've realized the file is an `x-zip-compressed`.  I've tried looking more closely into what that means for unzipping but I haven't nailed the specifics yet.

Comment: On the same note, the only way I can reproduce your error is when I give it non-zip file to unzip. I Think you are on the right track, there is nothing wrong with the code. Rather I think it has to do with fact that compression algorithm is not recognized by the Utilities.unzip. To test the same, compress a bunch of files in google drive using google drive compression software and then unzip using the code. It should work!

Answer (score 4):

I was running into the same "Invalid arguments" error in my testing, so instead of using:

```
file.setContent('application/zip')
```

I used:

```
file.setContentTypeFromExtension();
```

And, that solved the problem for me. Also, as @tukusejssirs mentioned, a zip file can contain multiple files, so unzip() returns an array of blobs (as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzip(BlobSource))). That means you either need to loop through the files, or if you know you only have one, explicitly reference it's position in the array, like this:

```
var fileUnzipped = folder.createFile(fileUnzippedBlob[0])
```

Here's my entire script, which covers both of these issues:

```
/**
 * Fetches a zip file from a URL, unzips it, then uploads a new file to the user's Drive.
 */
function uploadFile() {
  var url = '<url goes here>';
  var zip = UrlFetchApp.fetch('url').getBlob();

  zip.setContentTypeFromExtension();

  var unzippedFile = Utilities.unzip(zip);
  var filename = unzippedFile[0].getName();
  var contentType = unzippedFile[0].getContentType();
  var csv = unzippedFile[0];

  var file = {
    title: filename,
    mimeType: contentType
  };

  file = Drive.Files.insert(file, csv);
  Logger.log('ID: %s, File size (bytes): %s', file.id, file.fileSize);

  var fileId = file.id;

  // Move the file to a specific folder within Drive (Link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/<folderId>)
  var folderId = '<folderId>';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var driveFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);

  folder.addFile(driveFile);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question may be found here. [Is there a size limit to a blob for Utilities.unzip(blob) in Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830261/is-there-a-size-limit-to-a-blob-for-utilities-unzipblob-in-google-apps-script)
 If the download is over 100 mb the full file cannot be downloaded. Due to that it will not be in the proper zip format. Throwing the cannot unzip file error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the creation of the blob from a file (in this case the `.zip` file) requires the `.next()`; otherwise it did not work for me.

Also note that the `.zip` file might contain more than one file, therefore I included a `for` cycle.

Anyway, my working/tested solution/script is the following:

```
function unzip(folderName, fileZipName){
  // Variables
  // var folderName = "folder_name";
  // var fileZipName = "file_name.zip";
  var folderId = getFolderId(folderName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var fileZip = folder.getFilesByName(fileZipName);
  var fileExtractedBlob, fileZipBlob, i;

  // Decompression
  fileZipBlob = fileZip.next().getBlob();
  fileZipBlob.setContentType("application/zip");
  fileExtractedBlob = Utilities.unzip(fileZipBlob);
  for (i=0; i < fileExtractedBlob.length; i++){
    folder.createFile(fileExtractedBlob[i]);
  }
}
```