# Utilities.unzip doesn't work for zip files containing subfolders

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, unzip, utilities

I'm trying to write some Google Apps Script to extract a zip file which has 3 subfolders. Depending on the folder, I will then run through the various files and process them accordingly.

I cannot get Utilities.unzip to work when the zip file contains subfolders. I tested my code with a simple zip file and it worked as expected, so I'm guessing it is something I am missing or the .unzip simply does not work on subfolders.

Is there anyway to get this to work? Or can I extract the files via javascript and pass these to the apps script? I had a look at a couple of javascript libraries that do this but couldn't work out how to import these into my Google Web App.

UPDATE: Here is the code I have been using to test:

```
function ExtractSecurityZip() {

var iZIP =DriveApp.getFileById("1RAhI_mGQHay9boCQ9tt5T_0iqF6w5Eky").getBlob().setContentTypeFromExtension()

Utilities.unzip(iZIP)

return

}
```

I am not concerned about maintaining the folder structure in the zip file, I just need all the files.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Dave

PS: If it helps, the zip file is an Oracle LCM Export, so I cannot remove the folder structure.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48406765/1595451)

Comment: And, as the additional information for @Rubén 's comment, can you provide the sample ZIP file for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike I don't think the op really cares about a unique file structure.  I think he would like a solution that would work for any file structure.

Comment: Apologies I have added the code now. @Tanaike, Cooper is correct, I don't need to maintain the file structure, I just want all of the files within the ZIP file. Thanks

Comment: I see [this utility](https://github.com/tanaikech/UnzipGs) from @Tanaike uses a 3rd party JS zip utility, wrapped in a Google Script. I have not tried it (yet) and I see it is specifically designed to handle password-protected zips. But I expect this is the way to go if, like me, your zip file was not created using Google's zip utility (see my notes in the answer below).

Answer (score 2):

This will unzip all the the files to a destination directory

```
function getAllZips(dstdir,zipid) {
  const dstFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dstdir);
  const zipFile = DriveApp.getFileById(zipid);
  const blobs = Utilities.unzip(zipFile.getBlob());
  blobs.forEach((b,i) => {
    let pA = b.getName().split('/');
    if(pA[pA.length-1]) {
      dstFolder.createFile(b).setName(pA[pA.length-1]);
    }
  });
}
```

Here's what looping through blobs.getName() reveals:

| Name |
| --- |
| SO Snippets/ |
| SO Snippets/addCheckboxes |
| SO Snippets/appendIdtolocalStorage |
| SO Snippets/clearAllIdsFromLocalStorage |
| SO Snippets/clearIdsFromLocalStorage |
| SO Snippets/dataUrl |
| SO Snippets/delCheckedQuestion |
| SO Snippets/delCheckedQuestions |
| SO Snippets/delUnWantedQuestions |
| SO Snippets/getCurrentIdsInLocalStorage |
| SO Snippets/loadIdsIntoLocalStorage |
| SO Snippets/refreshPage |
| SO Snippets/remDupsSort |
| SO Snippets/removeFooter%26SideBar |
| SO Snippets/removeSomeIds |
| SO Snippets/removeSomeOlderIds |
| SO Snippets/viewCookies |
| SO Snippets/zButton |

The ones that end in '/' are directories the others are files.  I messed around with trying to restore the directory structure but it's a bit more work than I thought.  So  you might want to add the Javascript Tag to your list of tags.  My guess is that one of them have already figured it out.

With regard to the question asked by  andrewjames: Can you run this on your zip file so that I can see what it looks like?

```
function lookingInTheBlob(zipid='1QnrP-1lngoLQtNsqd373_UytVptuqoI1') {
  const zipFile = DriveApp.getFileById(zipid);
  const blobs = Utilities.unzip(zipFile.getBlob());
  let data = [];
  blobs.forEach((b,i) => {data.push([b.getName()]);});
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  sh.clearContents();
  sh.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: I am interested in this question - but I have been unable to use the above code successfully. I created a zip file on my local Windows drive, using 7-Zip (with default settings). The zip contains a mixture of text files, and folders containing other text files and folders. I dragged and dropped the resulting zip file into my Google Drive location. When I try to run the above code, it fails here: `const blobs = Utilities.unzip(zipFile.getBlob());`. Error: `Exception: Invalid argument`. I can export the zip file from my Google Drive and unzip it with 7-Zip OK. What did I do wrong?

Comment: @andrewjames I added some code for you to run so that I can see what the blob looks like.

Comment: Oh I just noticed the problem with the code.  I guess  you can't run it.  I don't really know too much of different zip formats so it may be some other kind of format.

Comment: I used my zip file's Google doc ID and checked by adding `console.log(zipFile.getName());` - which gave the expected file name. But `const blobs = Utilities.unzip(zipFile.getBlob());` throws the same error as previously: _Exception: Invalid argument_. This `zipFile.getBlob().getContentType()` gives `application/x-zip-compressed`, as expected. And even the byte array `zipFile.getBlob().getBytes()` matches the original byte array of the zip file on my C drive.

Comment: Ah - OK. How did you create your zip? Using Google Script's `zip()` I assume?

Comment: No.  I used winzip

Comment: @Cooper thanks for this, this works for most of my zip files. Frustratingly though, it doesn't work on the ones directly exported from Oracle LCM. As a test, I tried both your scripts with: the untouched exported zip file, and the same file, but extracted then compressed using windows "send to", and the windows compressed works fine. They are both application/x-zip-compressed so I'm unsure where to go now, but I suspect the workaround will be to extract, then compress again before running through the script. Appreciate your help,

Comment: Yeah I'm not surprized that it doesn't work on all of them because I'm not familiar with the different formats.